# After ending the scene need to start new scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean, 2d, scene2d

I'm doing an educational game for kids..
But I stopped at the end of the scene
I could not make a code to start the new scene..
in the First Script 
when play game the scenes does not stop until the last scene.

```c#
YouWin.pictureInPlace++;
```

I searched a lot and did not find my question, so I consulted you. It was easier to do a button to go to the Next scene but I prefer to do it automaticly
I think this task can be accomplished by the boolean but its need to reference  game object.. and the script on 2 images.
The First Script (Manager) has put on Four images At Canvas..
The second one (YouWin) I put on empty GameObject..
thanks for the help

The first script (Manger)

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Manager : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler
{
    Vector2 pos1;
    public GameObject pos2;
    private bool canMove;
    public GameObject winner;
    void Start()
    {
        pos1 = transform.position;
        canMove = true;
    }

    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log(eventData);
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        if (canMove)
            transform.position = Input.mousePosition;       
    }

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, pos2.transform.position);
        if (distance < 50)
        {
            transform.position = pos2.transform.position;
            transform.localScale = pos2.transform.localScale;
            canMove = false;
            winner.GetComponent<YouWin>().pictureInPlace++;   
        }
        else
        {
            transform.position = pos1;
        }
    }  
}
```

The second script (YouWin)

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class YouWin : MonoBehaviour
{
public int NumberOfImages;
public int pictureInPlace;
public string sceneName;

    void Update()
    {
        if (pictureInPlace == NumberOfImages)
        {
            StartCoroutine(LoadScene());
            Debug.Log("You Win!");
        }
    }

    IEnumerator LoadScene()
    {
       yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.5f);
        SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName);

    }
}
```

Comment: `async` is a keyword and therefore you can't call  a variable `async` ... you actually should get a compiler error from `AsyncOperation async = ...`. also what do you store it in a variable for if you never use it anyway? Just call `SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneName);` why is `pictureInPlace` static and `NumberOfImages` not? Do you get the `Debug.Log` "you win"?

Comment: this is atutorial where i get my code but i modified it [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KL7ACZiKZpg&lc=z22yvdtbuwqmhvxy304t1aokgwxwskiifcgjodfgp42lrk0h00410.1548946308066743&pbjreload=10) and the code is working fine no bugs no errors untill now but about `SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(sceneName);` or `AsyncOperation async = ...` this is not the problem im just trying codes but i need to start next scene after matching images in the scene thats all Even if it was to cancel the current code and create a new code in `YouWin` script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**After all thanks for helping me but I was able to find the right solution
just make in the first Script (Manager) :**

```
bool static Done;
void Start()
    {
bool Done = false;
    }
 public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, pos2.transform.position);
        if (distance < 50)
        {
            transform.position = pos2.transform.position;
            transform.localScale = pos2.transform.localScale;
            canMove = false;
            bool Done = True; 
        }
}
```

and just call it from the second Script (YouWin)

```
public string sceneName;
void Update()
{
if(Youwin.Done)
{
 StartCoroutine(LoadScene());
}
}

IEnumerator LoadScene()
    {

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneName);

    }
```

This IS The right solution ;

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you didn't reference *YouWin* in your *Manager* script. You should include it by adding it as a global variable `public YouWin <variable_name>;` or by referencing your empty GameObject and getting the *YouWin* component:

```
public GameObject emptyObject;

emptyObject.GetComponent<YouWin>().picturesInPlace++;
```

Comment: im trying to make boolean to make At Manager Script
like:
'public bool whenlDone;
whenlDone = True; '
but even i reference it in youWin Script nothing Happen

Comment: @Mohamedessam please avoid to write everything in **bold**! I already edited your answer but also avoidnl it in the comments .. it is ment to be used to emphasize certain keywords not for using it on an entire paragraph.

Comment: @Savaria `pictureInPlace` is **static** and therefore the call of `YouWin.pictureInPlace++;` valid

Comment: But he is just calling YouWin without referencing the script or extracting the component. Therefore, YouWin is just an undeclared variable and has no attribute `pictureInPlace`.

Comment: Unfortunately, as I explained earlier, while running the game, the Scenes quickly scuttled without I matching any images and the the same if reference or not .. any other Solution please .. –

Comment: @Savaria `YouWin` is the class `YouWin` itself ... and again: `pictureInPlace` is [**static**](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static) and therefore belongs to the class `YouWin` itself, not to an instance

Comment: look at my modified script its still Not effective what i must do to go to the next scene after matching my Located scene @derHugo